# Capturing network data that flows through a USB modem

Tags: c#, sockets, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I am trying to capture network packets from several interfaces at the same time. I can do this with the below mentioned code, but if i connect a USB modem an exception comes when that IP is selected. The exception comes from the line `mainSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, byTrue, byOut)`.

The exception is

> "The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced."

```
class SetIp
{
    private Socket mainSocket;
    private byte[] byteData = new byte[4096];

    public void setIP(IPAddress add)
    {
        mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
        mainSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(add, 0));
        mainSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);
        Thread MyThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] byTrue = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
                byte[] byOut = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }; //Capture outgoing packets

                mainSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, byTrue, byOut);

                mainSocket.Receive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None);

                ParseData(byteData, byteData.Length);

            }
        }));
        MyThread.Start();

    }
```

Comment: What is the exact exception? Does it has an InnerException?

Comment: @rene sorry i am new to this, anyway i edited the question and added the exception

Comment: Is it a [SocketException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception(v=vs.110).aspx)? If yes, can you also add the Errorcode, NativeErrorcode and SocketErrorcode. Did you try to run this code NOT within a thread?

Comment: @rene it is a SocketException. Code is <0x80004005>.

Comment: @rene after using the try catch for that line of code, i can see data been captured after the exception. Don't know why that is?

Comment: That could be an unauthorized error. Can you try running your app elevated? (Run as Administator)

Comment: @rene it is already Run as Administrator.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm out of options in that case. It might be an issue with that specific make of the usb modem...